# Rescale image so width is half the size of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, image-scaling

I'm fairly new to swift and I'm currently trying to display multiple image views within a custom UITableCell.

Ideally, I would like to have each image be scaled so that its width fills half of the screen size (while preserving the original aspect ratio).

The idea is that each UITableCell will have a collage of 3 images and some additional information in a UILabel -- the tallest image would sit in its own column with the smaller two stacked right next to the tallest. Below is a screenshot to help illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

However, I'm having some trouble with this.  Currently, once I've retrieved an image with an Alamofire .GET request, I call a function that does the below:

```
let aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
let newHeight = desiredWidth / aspectRatio

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, newHeight))
image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, newHeight))

let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return scaledImage
```

Once the image is returned, before adding it to the first image view, I update the frame of the image view as follows:

```
      cell.img_1.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: new_image.size.width, height: new_image.size.height)

      cell.img_1.image = new_image
```

However, when I run the code, the width of the images is not half of the screen-- rather- they look exactly the same as they would if I put them into the image view without scaling (the ImageView is set to Aspect Fit Mode).

When I print out the width and height of the newly scaled images the values ARE consistent with what I want.

I do notice that the pre-scale and post-scale aspect ratios are slightly off by ~.01. -- so given that the image view is set to Aspect Fit, could this explain what I am seeing?

I've also tried this with the mode set as Aspect Fill, but saw cases where the width of some images do not get scaled down properly, and take up more than half of the screen.

Apologies for the long-winded question, would greatly appreciate some help with this and I will provide more information if needed.  Thank you!

Comment: it's unclear whether or not you want to KEEP THE IMAGES THE SAME SHAPE AS THEIR ORIGINAL SHAPE.  do you want them to "stretch" one way or the  other to fit the final shape?  or do you want them to "letterbox" with a gap either at the top or sides, if  they are not the same SHAPE as the final box?

Comment: @Joe -- I'd like to preserve the original aspect ratios, so the shapes should stay the same.  I don't think I'll ever be filling the views with images that are smaller than the view itself-- at least not for now.

Comment: it's worth noting that as well as what Matt kindly explains below... It's very likely Shaun, you can, **in fact trivially achieve your goal, just using the correct setting** on the options there.  What i mean is, **do absolutely nothing in code**, just allow the iOS image display to size it for you.  You may be doing a big "facepalm" in a few minutes when you try it  :)

Comment: note that to some extent the more difficult solution to what you are trying to acvhieve is to use dynamically sized table views. that is very hard indeed, I always find.  I don't think you need anything like that tough.  i think you're literally just not selecting the right sizing option for the image, and you should delet all your code that attempts to resize (stretch .. whatever) the image.

Comment: I will play around with this tonight.. I have to say I felt like I was doing some overengineering.  However, my main goal here is to not have any whitespace between the images-- more for the aesthetic than anything else.  If I allow iOS to do autosizing, couldn't I have inconsistencies, ie, some cells with white space and some without?

Comment: hi shaun, you need to get clear in your head the difference between scaling it "uniformly" (the aspect ration never changes) and scaling it differently each way.  it completely depends on your project and the source material.  **say you get an image which is 10 pixels high and 5000 pixels wide** (sort of a thin banner). How would you display it?  What does it "mean" to say there will "never" be white space? your question has been more than answered here.  in the first instance, become expert with what has been pointed out on this QA. then, move on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ImageView is set to Aspect Fit Mode).

But there's your problem - or one of them. If you don't want an image view to resize the image, don't use *any* "aspect" content mode, nor any "fit" or "fill" content mode. Use, for example, Center.

Comment: Going to try this now

Comment: Might not give exactly what you are after, but at least your efforts in sizing the image will not be ignored!

Comment: By the way, never call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. Always use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, with the last argument `0`. Otherwise your image will look poor on high resolution screens (which is most of them these days).

Comment: Thanks-- that worked!! And will do.  As a follow up question-- i'd like the height of my cells to wrap around the content. I have provided an estimated row height as well as specified "tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension",  but currently my images are running into the next cells...

Comment: You don't really get a follow up question - at least, not in comments. That's called "leeching" and is considered bad form. I've answered the question you asked! If I helped you, please consider accepting my answer. If you have another question - and I'm sure you do - ask a completely new question. I (and many others) will be happy to help.

Comment: My apologies, I almost asked about that before asking! Will post another question. Thanks!

Comment: And I will accept as soon as it lets me, its saying 3 minutes left.

Comment: I'll watch for your followup question because I already know what it is! :)))))

Comment: Okay will draft it up now! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77568/discussion-between-shaunvxc-and-matt).

Comment: dude it's somewhat unlikely anyone will have time to chat with you on such a question  :)