# Issue with image scaling in Swift on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am fairly new to swift, and have currently ran into an issue when trying to scale an image to fit the full width of the screen. Since the image is of varying height, I would like to if possible to simply set its width property to the screen width, and allow the height to scale accordingly  (It's intrinsic size has been set as "Place Holder"). I am using the following code to scale the image:

```
imgPrimaryImg.image = ImageHelper.loadImage(product.defaultImage)
imgPrimaryImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

The problem is that with ScaleAspectFit, there is alot of transparent background (I set background colour to blue for clarity - if it were transparent the issue still remains, I tried it)

[Broken image design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwG9B.png)

Is there anyway I can set it up so that the transparent part of the background is not rendered (or at least not shown as it is completely breaking the design)

Not sure if it might help but this is the rest of the setup

[Storyboard setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbhQu.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Attribute inspector http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y04w0.png

 Size inspector http://i.stack.imgur.com/vK5HA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after further research I managed to find a question which took into consideration my situation and managed to solve the issue:

```
let aspectRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height
let newHeight = desiredWidth / aspectRatio

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(desiredWidth, newHeight))
image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, newHeight))

let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return scaledImage
```

And passed the current screen width as "desiredWidth" (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width).

The original post was [Rescale image so width is half the size of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180514/rescale-image-so-width-is-half-the-size-of-screen?rq=1) in case anyone might ever run into the same problem